# Mac Mini 2014 No input devices found

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, audio

I have some issues on the new Mac Mini 2014, when I'm running my application, I've got the crash, when the application uses some audio calls.

For example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The issue is that we always receive nil input device.

And I went to settings on my Mac. I've seen the following:

[image]

No input devices found. Why???

And I see on my old Mac Mini 2012:

[image]

If I insert jack into line in, the issue is fixed. But it's some lifehack :)

Anyone else encountered this problem? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: why not do proper error checking in your code for when MacOS reports back no input devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later model mac mini's have hardware to detect when a cable is inserted and use that to add or remove the audio input device. A lot of PCs have been doing this for awhile now. There is no workaround to this that I know of.

So the correct way to answer you is to say that you need to check return values and add proper handling in your code to deal with the case where no input device is present. For example, in your call to `alcOpenDevice` I can see that `deviceName` is `nil`. You should probably be testing for this condition rather than marching blindly along until you get a null reference exception.